# Matlab: Avoid for-loop by using clever matrix indexing & find? How?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I've been getting into Matlab more and more lately and another question came up during my latest project.
I generate several rectangles (or meshs) within an overall boundary.
These meshs can have varying spacings/intervals.

I do so, because I want to decrease the mesh/pixel resolution of certain areas of a digital elevation model. So far, everything works fine.
But because the rectangles can be chosen in a GUI, it might happen that the rectangles overlap. This overlap is what I want to find, and remove. Would they have the same spacing, e.g. rectangle 1&2 would look something like this:

```
[t1x, t1y] = meshgrid(1:1:9,1:1:9);
[t2x, t2y] = meshgrid(7:1:15,7:1:15);
[t3x, t3y] = meshgrid(5:1:17,7:1:24);
```

In this case, I could just use unique, to find the overlapping areas.
However, they look more like this:

```
[t1x, t1y] = meshgrid(1:2:9,1:2:9);
[t2x, t2y] = meshgrid(7:3:15,7:3:15);
[t3x, t3y] = meshgrid(5:4:17,7:4:24);
```

Therefore, unique cannot be applied, because mesh 1 might very well overlap with mesh 2 without having the same nodes. For convenience and further processing, all rectangles / meshes are brought into column notation and put in one result matrix within my code:

```
result = [[t1x(:), t1y(:)]; [t2x(:), t2y(:)]; [t3x(:), t3y(:)]];
```

Now I was thinking about using 2 nested for-loops to solve this problem, sth like this (which does not quite work yet):

```
res = zeros(length(result),1);
for i=1:length(result)
    currX = result(i,1);
    currY = result(i,2);
    for j=1:length(result)
        if result(j,1)< currX < result(j+1,1) && result(j,2)< currY < result(j+1,2)
              res(j) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

BUT: First of all, this does not quite work yet, because I get an out of bounds error due to length(result)=j+1 and moreover, res(j) = 1 seems to get overwritten by the loop.
But this was just for testing and demonstratin anyway.
Because the meshes shown here are just examples, and the ones I use are fairly big, the result Matrix contains up to 2000x2000 = 4 mio nodes --> lenght(result) ~4mio.
Putting this into a nested for-loop running over the entire length will most likely kill my memory.

Therefore I was hoping to find a sophisticade solution which does not require a nested loop, but takes advantage of Matlabs find and clever matrix indexing.
I am not able to think of something, but was hoping to get help here.

Discussions and help is very much appreciated!

Cheers,

Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here follows a quick stab (not extensively tested):

```
% Example meshes
[t1x, t1y] = meshgrid(1:2:9,1:2:9);
[t2x, t2y] = meshgrid(7:3:15,7:3:15);

% Group points for convenience
A = [t1x(:), t1y(:)];
B = [t2x(:), t2y(:)];

% Compare which points of A within edges of B (and viceversa)
idxA = A(:,1) >= B(1,1) & A(:,1) <= B(end,1) & A(:,2) >= B(1,2) & A(:,2) <= B(end,2);
idxB = B(:,1) >= A(1,1) & B(:,1) <= A(end,1) & B(:,2) >= A(1,2) & B(:,2) <= A(end,2);

% Plot result of identified points
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2), '*r')
hold on
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2), '*b')
plot([A(idxA,1); B(idxB,1)], [A(idxA,2); B(idxB,2)], 'sk')
```

I squared the points that were identified as overlapping:

[image: Overlapping meshes]

Also, related to your question is this [Puzzler: overlapping rectangles](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/07/14/puzzler-overlapping-rectangles/) by Doug Hull of TMW.

Comment: Dear Oleg, 

Thank you very much for this idea and the posted link! Indeed, this works very well in the case of two rectangles. But I should have mentioned that my problem involves an arbitrary number of rectangles all in the same plane, which might, or might not, overlap, which complicates the case quite a bit. That's why I was interesed in finding a solution that works with one long result matrix nx2 and checks overlap within this matrix, rather than having to test each individual rectangle aganinst the others. This is what really puzzles me.
Edit:I added another rectangle to avoid confusion

Comment: I can think of two potential solutions: 1) resample the rectangles with minimal step such that all original points are included in the new resampled grid, then call unique and convert back to original. The hard part is to find the step. This approach is more RAM intensive.
2) smart pairwise comparison. First, create/store your rectangles in a cell array or struct. To speed things, first up check that rectangles overlap at all then write off those which have been already covered by others (you can perform a one way idx instead of both ways).

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I already started and just finished working on something comparable to your solution 2). I used rectint to see which rectangles have overlapping areas >0, stored those, stripped off double-entries and then ran your suggested logical operations. Works decent now. Thanks again!